# matrices too big to fit the width of a page

Tags: matrices, scaling, width

When I type matrices in `beamer` class, they are often too big to fit the width of a page. What is the way to make the matrices smaller? I also want to make the font of the entries of these matrices smaller. I used

```
\[ \scriptscriptstyle
M_{1,k}  = \frac{1}{15} \left(
        \begin{array}{cccccccc}
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
         0 & 12k b_0 & (12k+15) b_1 & (12k+30) b_2 & (12k+45)  b_3 & (12k+60) b_4  \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
         0 & 2k  a_0 & (2k+5)  a_1 & (2k+10)  a_2 & 0 & 0   \\
        \end{array}
      \right)
\]
```

But it only makes the scaler 1/15 smaller, not the entries of this matrix. Is there a way to make the entries smaller, without typing `\scriptstyle` for each entries? Maybe something we can change the whole size by 75%, 50% of the content in `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`

Comment: put `\scriptsize` inside the array?

Comment: Also, don't do this. No-one will be able to read your slides if you make the text that small.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One quick (but not very beautiful) solution is to work with `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package, e.g.

```
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}

\[
M_{1,k}  = \frac{1}{15} \left(
    \scalemath{0.3}{
    \begin{array}{cccccccc}
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
     0 & 12k b_0 & (12k+15) b_1 & (12k+30) b_2 & (12k+45)  b_3 & (12k+60) b_4  \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
     0 & 2k  a_0 & (2k+5)  a_1 & (2k+10)  a_2 & 0 & 0   \\
    \end{array}
    }
  \right)
\]
```

Comment: A choice of `\scalemath{0.75}` will look quite a bit more beautiful; `\scalemath{0.3}` renders the contents virtually undecipherable...

Answer (score 22):

I suggest you insert, after the `\begin{frame}` statement but before the start of the equation, the following instructions.

```
\footnotesize
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt}
\medmuskip = 1mu % default: 4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
```

The command `\footnotesize` will bring about a roughly 20% reduction in fontsize; `\arraycolsep=3pt` cuts about 40% from the whitespace that gets inserted between columns (useful because you have 7 such whitespaces), and `\medmuskip=1mu` drastically reduces the amount of whitespace TeX inserts before and after each "+" symbol (and all other symbols of class "mathbin").

Here's a complete MWE and its output:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt} % default: 5pt
\medmuskip = 1mu % default: 4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\[ 
M_{1,k}  = \frac{1}{15} 
\left( \begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 12k b_0 & (12k+15) b_1 & (12k+30) b_2 & (12k+45) b_3 & (12k+60) b_4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
0 & 2k  a_0 & (2k+5)  a_1 & (2k+10)  a_2 & 0 & 0   \\
\end{array} \right)
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** If you need to economize further on whitespace, you could (i) reduce the whitespace around the equal sign by issuing the command `\thickmuskip = 2mu` and (ii) replace the array preamble line `\begin{array}{rrrrrr}` with `\begin{array}{@{}rrrrrr@{}}`; the latter measure will eliminate the whitespace between the opening and closing large parentheses and the first/last column of numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Resize the width to `\linewidth`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
$\displaystyle
M_{1,k}  = \frac{1}{15} 
\left( \begin{array}{rrrrrrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 12k b_0 & (12k+15) b_1 & (12k+30) b_2 & (12k+45)  b_3 & (12k+60) b_4  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
0 & 2k  a_0 & (2k+5)  a_1 & (2k+10)  a_2 & 0 & 0   \\
\end{array} \right)
$}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```