# font size in math mode (for an exponentiated matrix)

Tags: matrices, scaling, scalebox

Note: While I am interested in typesetting the Euler constant raised to the power of a matrix, I am more interested in understanding why the second version inserts a square dot, and why the third doesn't compile.

First, what works: I have adapted the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43065/matrices-too-big-to-fit-the-width-of-a-page), (defining a new command). Second, when I try incorporating more of the suggestions, I get an odd square dot below the “g” in word “beginning.”[image]

Third, using scalebox directly from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170137/font-size-in-math-mode), my code fails to compile at all.

I am missing something obvious, but would appreciate an explanation.

[Removing the first `\end{document}` command reveals the compilation error. It wants mathmode.]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
% The Euler number, `e'.
\newcommand{\eu}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}
\newcommand{\du}{\ensuremath{\mathop{}\!\textnormal{\slshape d}}} % the command \du gives a slant roman differential operator, distinguished from either an italic math variable d or a math operator with d.

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is what I get without messing with things:$
\eu^{\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1&2 \\ 3&4 \end{array}\right]}$. Obviously, not good.

The following two versions compile, and the matrix has dimensions similar to those of the $\frac{\du}{\du x}$ operator from the previous term. Optically, however, each looks horrible. \\

\[
    \eu^{\pi}, \eu^{\sqrt[3]{2}}, \eu^i, e^{3-4i}, \eu^{\frac{\du}{\du x}}, {
\eu^{\scalemath{0.4}{%
        {\left[
        \begin{array}{cc} 
            a&b \\ 
            c&d 
        \end{array}
        \right]}
        }}};
\]

[Inserting frames and making more adjustment looks like this, which I \emph{think} improves the look of the matrix, but introduces a square dot at the beginning of the line. I can't figure out how to get rid of it.]

\begin{frame} % inserts square dot that I don't understand
\footnotesize
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt} % default: 5pt
\medmuskip = 1mu % default: 4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\[
    \eu^{\pi}, \eu^{\sqrt[3]{2}}, \eu^i, e^{3-4i}, \eu^{\frac{\du}{\du x}}, {
\eu^{\scalemath{0.4}{%
        {\left[
        \begin{array}{cc} 
            a&b \\ 
            c&d 
        \end{array}
        \right]}
        }}};
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document} % on removing this line, the last example fails to compile

Why does scalemath seem to work, but scalebox not?

\[\eu^
{\scalebox{0.4}{%
        \left[
        \begin{array}{cc} 
            a&b \\ 
            c&d 
        \end{array}
        \right]}
        }
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\scalebox` is like `\mbox` and the content is always text mode, so you would need `$....$`  inside the box to get back to math (but I would never use scaling here) also never use `\\ ` at the  end of a paragraph, tex warns: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--15` (note 10000 is as bad as it gets, that is the maximum value of badness)

Comment: i'm certain i'm missing something, but i don't see the "odd square dot" you're referring to.  (i know the origin of one such dot, but don't want to try to explain it unless i know it's the same as what you're referring to,.)

Comment: I am adding (to the original question) a picture with the square dot. It appears below the ``g'' of the word ``beginning.''

Comment: What makes you think that the `amsart` class allows for a `frame` environment?

Comment: @David, the clarification on `\scalebox` working like `\mbox` was part of what I had been missing. Badness 10000 is _pretty_ bad <grin>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to use scaling (which introduces inconsistent font sizes and spacing)  Just use a `smallmatrix` at scriptsize:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\newcommand{\eu}{\mathrm{e}}
\newcommand{\du}{\mathop{}\!\textnormal{\slshape d}} % the command \du gives a slant roman differential operator, distinguished from either an italic math variable d or a math operator with d.

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is what I get without messing with things:$
\eu^{\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1&2 \\ 3&4 \end{array}\right]}$. Obviously, not good.

The following two versions compile, and the matrix has dimensions similar to those of the $\frac{\du}{\du x}$ operator from the previous term. Optically, however, each looks horrible.
\[
    \eu^{\pi}, \eu^{\sqrt[3]{2}}, \eu^i, e^{3-4i}, \eu^{\frac{\du}{\du x}}, 
        \eu^{\text{$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
            a&b \\ 
            c&d 
        \end{smallmatrix}\right]$}};
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: I have gone with the smallmatrix (for now) in my document. I had forgotten about this option.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a variant of `smallmatrix`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 

% The Euler number, `e'.
\newcommand{\eu}{\mathrm{e}}
\newcommand{\du}{\mathop{}\!\textnormal{\slshape d}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{smallermatrix}{\null\,\vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@\restore@math@cr\default@tag
  \baselineskip4\ex@ \lineskip1.2\ex@ \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup\hfil$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil&&\thickspace\hfil
  $\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil\crcr
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup\,%
}
\newenvironment{bsmallermatrix}
 {\left[\smallermatrix}
 {\endsmallermatrix\right]}
\newenvironment{bsmallmatrix}
 {\left[\smallmatrix}
 {\endsmallmatrix\right]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\eu^{\begin{bsmallermatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bsmallermatrix}}
=
\exp(\begin{bsmallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bsmallmatrix})
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your method gives not so nice results; I removed all unnecessary braces.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}}
% The Euler number, `e'.
\newcommand{\eu}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}
\newcommand{\du}{\ensuremath{\mathop{}\!\textnormal{\slshape d}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\eu^{\pi}, \eu^{\sqrt[3]{2}}, \eu^i, e^{3-4i}, \eu^{\frac{\du}{\du x}},
\eu^{\scalemath{0.4}{%
  \begin{bmatrix}
  a&b \\ 
  c&d 
  \end{bmatrix}
  }};
\]

\footnotesize
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt} % default: 5pt
\medmuskip = 1mu % default: 4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\[
\eu^{\pi}, \eu^{\sqrt[3]{2}}, \eu^i, e^{3-4i}, \eu^{\frac{\du}{\du x}},
\eu^{\scalemath{0.4}{%
  \begin{bmatrix}
  a&b \\ 
  c&d 
  \end{bmatrix}
  }};
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

About your problem with `frame`, the explanation is very easy. The LaTeX kernel defines a `\frame` command that takes an argument and boxes it. In your case the argument is `\footnotesize`, so LaTeX will box it, resulting in no contents and therefore a very tiny box (the square dot you see).

Just don't use `frame` as an environment: it doesn't exist and `\begin{frame}` does not produce an error because `\frame` does exist, but, as you see, does a rather different thing than what you may be expecting. What you get, apart from the small box, is confining the setting of `\arraycolsep` and `\medmuskip` in the group created by `\begin` and `\end`.

Comment: since `amsart` automatically loads `amsmath`, it's not necessary to load it.  (i know.  the original question didn't specify document class, and if it's not one from ams, `amsmath` *does* have to be loaded explicitly.)

Comment: @egreg that explains my little square dot!

Comment: I've gone with the smallmatrix, simply because I am not sure that I could troubleshoot the smallermatrix if I were to come back to it in several years and want to make an adjustment.